# Enable webRequest Permission to use Downloads API for LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, iframe, browser, conga-composer

I'm looking for a way to know when a download is completed via event in the browser. I have an LWC kicking off the download event, but the Conga solution I'm using (due to iFrame/CORS issues), I have no way of knowing when its completed.

The [Downloads.onChanged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/onChanged) event seems to fit the bill by way of event listeners, but it needs to be enabled by allowing it via [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#api_permissions).

Has anyone had any luck enabling the *webRequest* permission for use in an LWC?